# Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to store my output in a txt file
this one is working good so far

```
 SELECT * FROM #HashTable

Output 
------
Data
```

But when i am trying to write the output in txt file i am getting the error

```
exec sp_configure 'allow updates',0
GO
Reconfigure


SELECT * FROM #HashTable

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'MKDIR "C:\test\File4.txt"'
DECLARE @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100) ,    @FilePath NVARCHAR(100) ,    @bcpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)



SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM #HashTable" queryout '
SET @FilePath = 'C:\test\'
SET @OutputFile = 'File4.txt'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Comment: Does the SQL Server Service account have access to the path `C:\test`?

Comment: So the `mkdir "C:\test\File4.txt"` command will either 1) fail if `C:\test` doesn't already exist, or 2) create a directory named `C:\test\file4.txt` which will then prevent BCP from writing to a file named `C:\test\file4.txt`. If you have a look on the SQL Server what combination of directories and files are there in `C:\test` and `C:\test\File4.txt`?

Comment: What's the error?